# C# Threading process

Tags: c#, winforms

Program.cs

```
using (Login login = new Login())
{ 
    login.ShowDialog(); //Close this form after login is correct in login form button_click
}
if (isValiduser == true) //Static variable created in application to check user
{           
     Application.Run(new MainInterface());
}
```

Login form click event

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(isValiduser == true)
   {
      this.Close();
   }
 else
   {
      //else part code
   }
}
```

According to this code when we Click on Login event in Login form and isValiduser return true then Program.cs will run `MainInterface` form. but actually, this code is not run `Application.Run(new MainInterface())`;
So, could anyone tell me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Where are you assigning btnLogin_Click as the event handler for one of the buttons on your login dialog?

Comment: Also, your title is misleading, as this doesn't appear to be dealing with threading.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't understand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't understand. let me tell you about my purpose again: I have 2 forms: 1st is Login form and 2nd is Main form. at the first time of I want to run Login form after the username and password are correct then Mainform was call to run by Program.cs( Application.Run(new Mainform());),and for login form just showdialog is not Application in it.

Comment: How are you making sure that btnLogin_Click gets called when the appropriate button is clicked?

Comment: And what is related to threading? Do you set up two messag pumps? if not, then there is ONE Thread. ONE - ONLY. UI is not multi threaded.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in `Program.CS` should be

```
 using (Login login = new Login())
    { 
         login.ShowDialog(); //Close this form after login is correct in login form button_click
         if (isValiduser == true) //Static variable created in application to check user
         {           
            Application.Run(new MainInterface());
         }
    }
```

And your login click event should be like that

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          if(isValiduser == true)
           {
              //this.Close();
              this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
           }
         else
           {
              //else part code
           }
        }
```

Comment: There is no change, when `this.Close()` and `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` program goes back to main thread.

Answer (score 0):

problem is you are not set `isValiduser` as `true` in your code. so it will newer run `MainInterface` form.

Assume you have defined static variable called isValiduser in your Program.cs file as

```
static class Program
{
    public static bool isValiduser = false;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      // rest of your code
```

And then when you click login button you need to set this variable based on login status. 
you may need to have separate method for this.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // call validate user method and set value to `isValiduser`
    Program.isValiduser= IsValidUser("username", "password"); // here for testing i'm set it as true 
    if(Program.isValiduser== true)
    {
      this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
      //else part code
    }
}
```

you can have method to validate users

```
private bool IsValidUser(string name, string pw)
{
    return true; // impliment this method 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What I suspect is happening is that when you get to the `this.Close()` the control goes back to the main thread and the application ends (if there is no further code after it). i.e Your program starts from the first line of the main and ends at the last. So if you open your login form first then you need to open the MainInterface form before closing the login form.

Comment: since program go back to main thread you can open another form from there. no need to open form before closing another